# Get Value of HashMap using part of the key

Tags: java, regex, hashmap

I have an HashMap(String,Object). The key is combination of more than 1 unique ID. I have an input, a string which is part of the key(1 unique ID). I need to take the value in HashMap using that part of the key i have without iterating thousands of values in HashMap.

Can we achieve it using any Regex statement in HashMap.get()?

My Key is xxx.yyy.zzz where combination of xxx.zzz is unique throughout the Map. I have xxx and zzz as input. Also i have set of possible values of yyy(5-6 possibilities which may increase as well)for a given zzz.

I have two options to solve this now.

1. Map.Entry to check whether key starts and ends with xxx and zzz respectively
2. Trial and Error Method
    i. Form key xxx.yyy.zzz with all possible yyys and check for whether the key is present or not using .contains()
    ii. But this way, if i do .contains() 5-6 times for each call, won't it loop through 5-6 times at the worst case?
    iii. Also i am creating more strings in stringpool.

Which one should i prefer?

Comment: HashMap does not work for retrieval of parts of the key. You need to match it exactly for lookups.

Comment: who is downvoting all the answers here? Don't shoot the messenger. HashMap just doesn't do it...

Comment: how big is your data set and how often do you need to query it? A linear search through "thousands" of keys is probably not too terrible. "hundreds of thousands" could get you into trouble though.

Comment: @Thilo: It will range from thousands to hundreds of thousands as well.

Comment: Its total game of hash code value. If you can generate exact hash code for your key . You will win and you will get the corresponding value.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to retrieve a value from a `HashMap` without iterating over the entries/keys (which you don't want) is by searching for the full key.

If you require efficient search via a partial key, you should consider having a `HashMap` whose key is that partial key.

Comment: That would be a multi-map, though. Or maybe a nested Map (`Map<PartialKey, Map<FullKey, X>>`)

Comment: @Thilo Or a separate map for the partial keys, or the same map that contains multiple keys for the same value (both the full and partial keys).

Comment: I have proposed 2 solutions. Can you help me with finding the better one?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to use partial keys with a `HashMap`.

With `TreeMap` this can be achieved with a partial prefix of the wanted key, as it allows you to use `tailMap(String key)` to return a part of the map that would follow a specific key (i.e. your keypart). You'd still need to process the entries to see which ones would match the partial key.

Comment: TreeMap is a good choice for prefix searches (still does not work for arbitrary patterns).

Comment: If he does, he needs something like a Lucene keyword index.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are like `xxx.yyy.zzz` and you want to use `xxx.*` type access then you could consider my [MapFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17814755/823393) class.

It allows you to take a `Map` and filter it on a certain key prefix. This will do the searching for specific prefixes and retain the results of that search for later.

Answer (score 0):

> > Can we achieve it using any Regex statement in HashMap.get()?

No.You can't. You need to pass the exact key to get the associated value.

Alternatively, you should itertate ober keys and get the values matched to it. They you can have regex to match your input string against key.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using a `HashMap`.  However, you *can* use a `TreeMap` which will internally store the keys according to their natural order.  You can write a custom search method which will find the matching key, if it exists, in the set using the regex.  If written correctly, this will take `O(lgN)` time, which is substantially better than linear.  The problem reduces to searching for a `String` in an ordered list of `String`s.

As @Thilo pointed out, this solution assumes that you are trying to match a fragment of a key which starts at the beginning, and not anywhere else.

Comment: .. if you want prefix search, yes. Does not work if you have keys structured like "id1,id2,id3" (just one key) and want all with "id2".

Answer (score 0):

HashMap works on hashing algorithm that maintains hash buckets of hash code of keys and based on that hash code hash map retrieves corresponding value. For the you need to override **equals()** and **hashcode()** method for custom objects.

So

1. If you will try to get the value of a key, then key's hash code value get generated and further fetch operation happen based on that hash code.
2. **If you would not give a exact match of key how HashMap will find out that bucket with a wrong hashcode ?**